# Using best practice for chain responsibility in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have a scenario for login user. I write this code for check user if validate return success message.

I am using the chain responsibility pattern for this validation but it seems ugly because I need to more `new` in this class.

Now I want to write clean and best practice for using this pattern.

How can I do this ?

```
public abstract class ValidateUser
{
    protected readonly ValidateUser _validateUser;

    public ValidateUser(ValidateUser validateUser)
    {
        _validateUser = validateUser;
    }

    public abstract UserContext ValidateUserLogin(UserContext request);
}
```

CheckIsActive  :

```
public class CheckIsActive : ValidateUser
{
    public CheckIsActive(ValidateUser validateUser) : base(validateUser)
    {
    }

    public override UserContext ValidateUserLogin(UserContext request)
    {
        if (request.Context.IsActive)
        {
            return _validateUser.ValidateUserLogin(request);
        }

        return new UserContext
        {
            Message = "User Not Active"
        };
    }
}
```

CheckPhoneConfirmed :

```
public class CheckPhoneConfirmed : ValidateUser
{
    public CheckPhoneConfirmed(ValidateUser validateUser) : base(validateUser)
    {
    }

    public override UserContext ValidateUserLogin(UserContext request)
    {
        if (request.Context.ConfirmPhoneNumber)
        {
            return _validateUser.ValidateUserLogin(request);
        }

        return new UserContext
        {
            Message="Phone Number Not confirmed"
        };
    }
}
```

CheckIsLockedAccount  :

```
public  class CheckIsLockedAccount : ValidateUser
{
    public CheckIsLockedAccount(ValidateUser validateUser) : base(validateUser)
    {
    }

    public override UserContext ValidateUserLogin(UserContext request)
    {
        if (!request.Context.IsLockedEnd)
        {
            return new UserContext
            {
                Context = request.Context
            };
        }

        return new UserContext
        {
            Message = $"Your account is deactivated from to date {request.Context.LockedEnd}"
        };
    }
}
```

and I use this `Validate` by this way :

```
var validate = new CheckIsActive(new CheckPhoneConfirmed(new CheckIsLockedAccount(null)));
var validateUserContext = validate.ValidateUserLogin(new UserContext
                {
                    Context = findUSer.Result,
                    Message = null
                });
```

Comment: You can add a series of middlewares.

Comment: Without more info it feels like this is overkill here. You're basically trying to validate a user, which indicates you should be creating separate methods rather than concrete classes. Even the names of your concrete classes point towards they're not really classes. You might do something like this if you had a chain where you had a UserHandler that validated a user then passed it onto something like a RoleHandler to work out their permissions that passed it onto an OrderHandler or something.

Comment: @sr28 have you better idea for this work ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont feel like this pattern fits here for validation.

If you google you find following description of your pattern:

> Chain of Responsibility is behavioral design pattern that allows
>   passing request along the chain of potential handlers until one of
>   them handles request. The pattern allows multiple objects to handle
>   the request without coupling sender class to the concrete classes of
>   the receivers

I dont think any of that is the case in your solution. Since I feel you dont wanna handle different validations at different places?? I think you are missusing this pattern as a decorator pattern.

Instead try the following:

How about you split your objects into following:

First you need a abstract class so you can define later you validation rule

```
 public abstract class ValidationRule
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }

        public ValidationRule(string property)
        {
            Property = property;
            Error = property + " is not valid";
        }

        public ValidationRule(string property, string error)
            : this(property)
        {
            Error = error;
        }

        // validation method. To be implemented in derived classes

        public abstract bool Validate(Validator validator);

        // gets value for given business object's property using reflection

        protected object GetPropertyValue(Validator validator)
        {
            // note: reflection is relatively slow
            return validator.GetType().GetProperty(Property).GetValue(validator, null);
        }
    }
```

Then you can this class to make a more concrete validator. Maybe a finished rule or something you can even reuse more as for example:

```
public class ValidateRegex : ValidationRule
    {
        protected string Pattern { get; set; }

        public ValidateRegex(string propertyName, string pattern)
            : base(propertyName)
        {
            Pattern = pattern;
        }

        public ValidateRegex(string propertyName, string errorMessage, string pattern)
            : this(propertyName, pattern)
        {
            Error = errorMessage;
        }

        public override bool Validate(Validator validator)
        {
            return Regex.Match(GetPropertyValue(validator).ToString(), Pattern).Success;
        }
    }
```

and then make a final rule out of it

```
 public class ValidateEmail : ValidateRegex
    {
        public ValidateEmail(string propertyName) :
            base(propertyName, @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")
        {
            Error = propertyName + " is not a valid email address";
        }

        public ValidateEmail(string propertyName, string errorMessage) :
            this(propertyName)
        {
            Error = errorMessage;
        }
    }
```

The Validator can look something like this:

```
public abstract  class Validator
    {
        // list of business rules

        List<ValidationRule> rules = new List<ValidationRule>();

        // list of validation errors (following validation failure)

        List<string> errors = new List<string>();


        // gets list of validations errors

        public List<string> Errors
        {
            get { return errors; }
        }


        // adds a business rule to the business object

        protected void AddRule(ValidationRule rule)
        {
            rules.Add(rule);
        }

        // determines whether business rules are valid or not.
        // creates a list of validation errors when appropriate

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            bool valid = true;

            errors.Clear();

            foreach (var rule in rules)
            {
                if (!rule.Validate(this))
                {
                    valid = false;
                    errors.Add(rule.Error);
                }
            }
            return valid;
        }
    }
```

You can use now the validator as following (Note if constructor when you implement a lot of different validation rules):

```
public class Person : Validator
    {
        public Person ()
        {
            AddRule(new ValidateEmail("Email"));

            AddRule(new ValidateId("MemberId"));

            AddRule(new ValidateRequired("Email"));
            AddRule(new ValidateLength("Email", 1, 100));


            AddRule(new ValidateRequired("CompanyName"));
            AddRule(new ValidateLength("CompanyName", 1, 40));

            AddRule(new ValidateRequired("City"));
            AddRule(new ValidateLength("City", 1, 15));

            AddRule(new ValidateRequired("Country"));
            AddRule(new ValidateLength("Country", 1, 15));
        }



        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int NumOrders { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastOrderDate { get; set; }
    }
```

If you call now the IsValid() method all your validationrules get executed.

I feel like this is kinda what you want. If you dont wanna tie it to an object, you could try to create a standalone validator and  composite the validator into the class where you need it instead from deriving from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .net core Middleware pipeline, which is based upon Chain of Responsibility pattern only.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.HttpContext.User.HasClaim("IsLockedEnd", "true"))
    {
        await next();
    }                
});
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.HttpContext.User.HasClaim("ConfirmPhoneNumber", "true"))
    {
        await next();
    }
});
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.HttpContext.User.HasClaim("IsActive", "true"))
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

Comment: oh ok, you can use the way you want, I've just shown you an alternative way of implementing Chain of responsibility pattern using delegates, here you don't need to "new" here. You would just have to invoke the next  delegate or short circuit the pipeline.